# How can i enable native client in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, native-code, google-nativeclient

I want to enable native client support in chrome.
I went to about:flags and enabled it but it is still not working.

Comment: Are you using the dev channel version or the stable one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the following from the command-line

```
chrome.exe --enable-nacl
```

Refer to [this](http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/wiki/NativeClientInGoogleChrome)

Answer (score 3):

The page about:flags or better chrome://flags should works.

Search enable-nacl and click on the enable link
Go at the end of this page and don't forget to click on relaunch now

But don't activate enable-nacl-debug until you know how to launch the debugger. In this case your nacl module will wait debugger forever.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, Open terminal and type this command. Then click enter to execute the command.

```
google-chrome --enable-nacl
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Comment: Thanks for that. Have updated with more explanation on how to achieve this.